# UIButton under hidden UILabel won't work

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touch, uilabel, hidden

I have a large `UILabel` which I am using to cover a bunch of buttons while I do something else.
All I have set initially is `myLabel.hidden = YES;` so you can't see the `UILabel` but the `UIButtons` (below it) won't work anymore.

Is there another setting for the `UILabel` I can use to allow touches to go "through it" when it is hidden? Thanks.

Comment: Post some code of how you are connecting these labels and buttons and how the label is being hidden?

Comment: I simply do myLabel.hidden = YES; in ViewDidLoad. There is nothing else unusual about the buttons or label and the wiring.

Comment: If you don't want to go with Schnarchii's method, make sure you put `myLabel.enabled = NO;` as well.

Comment: still no good, I must have some other wierd thing I have missed, I'll let you all know... thx

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot! I had a uiScrollView in the way! sorry everyone, good useful code snippets here though.. thx

Answer (score 2):

why use a UILabel to cover your buttons.

just set

```
UIButton *button;
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

or

```
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: I don't want to see them during some UITextField editing. There are quite a few of them and this seemed like the fastest method, I'm very suprised a hidden label stops a button working!

Comment: you can hide your buttons too: [button setHidden:YES];

Comment: Yep, thx Schnarchii, I have a few states to store, some hidden some not etc, it would be a pain when I bring them all back..

Comment: It could be useful to have a UILabel over a button to have a background "UIVIew" (i.e., UIButton) that has things on it, but the the entire area of the background is clickable in the same way that a button is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `addSubView` and `removeFromSuperview` methods :

When you want to hide your UIButton with your UILabel :

```
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

and the contrary :

```
[myLabel removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why a hide is stopping the touch events on buttons. Anyways you can explicitly bring the buttons to foreground by the following calls.

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to use as a general way to hide or cover things just a straight UIView.  set:

```
[myCoverView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

and it will intercept touches and block touches to the buttons below it.

It should stop blocking touches when you hide it or turn the alpha to 0.0;
You can always siwtch the covering views interaction to:

```
[myCoverView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

and touches will pass through it.

If there is some reason that you need the UILabel these methods will work with it also.

Answer (score 0):

[myLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:NO].
Even if is hidden, your label will get the touches anyway. You have to disable that to achieve what u want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should hide your buttons instead of covering them with a label.

```
[yourButton setHidden = YES]; 
[yourButton2 setHidden = YES]; 
...
```